# Arborjs reading json data form php via json_encode

Tags: php, import, json, arbor.js

I am trying to export some data from a php script to load into arborjs, problem is the php json_encode encapsulates the node and edge objects in square brackets `[]`, which upsets arborjs.

json_encode gives:

```
{"nodes":[{"10":{"auth":"EP","depth":0}}]}
```

but arborjs wants

```
{"nodes":{"10":{"auth":"EP","depth":0}}}
```

Anyone else encountered and solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with `array_push`

```
$n=array($key=>$value);
array_push($array,$n);
```

does not preserve keys, instead using:

```
array_push($array[$key]);
$array[$key]=$value;
```

works, preserving keys.